# gcc ASAN doesn't stop on purported runtime error

Tags: c, gcc, address-sanitizer

I would like address sanitizer to abort when it catches something. I thought it was designed to do that by default but it does not seem to be working for me. I also tried `ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=1` which had no effect. Here are the details:

In a project I work on we use address sanitizer and it gave off this warning/error for weeks without anyone realizing it:

> runtime error: null pointer passed as argument xx, which is declared to never be null

Despite being called a runtime error it does not stop the program or cause a bad exit code. Here is a simple program to demonstrate it:

```
/*
gcc -fsanitize=address,undefined \
    -Wformat \
    -Werror=format-security \
    -Werror=array-bounds \
    -g -o xasan xasan.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  fprintf(stderr, "before\n");
  memcpy(NULL, argc > 1 ? "" : NULL, argc > 1 ? 1 : 0);
  fprintf(stderr, "after\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The argc trick is just so the gcc doesn't optimize out the memcpy call, basically in our code it ends up as `memcpy(dst, NULL, 0)` which causes the runtime error/warning.

I would expect that 'after' would not be output after the runtime error but it is and the program exit code is 0. Is this a bug? The manual says it's supposed to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error it turns out is from UBSAN and the answer is to use the compiler switch `-fno-sanitize-recover` as seen [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141031075119/http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan/).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to recompile, you can also run with `export UBSAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=1`.